I am trying to do CSS flex direction
I am facing a big problem in css flex direction coding.
I need first .column .left class in blue background and first .column .right class in red background. But second .column .left class in red background and second .column .right class in blue background.
Please check my codes.
<style>
.wrap {display:flex;}
.column {display:flex;flex-direction:row-reverse !important}
</style>


<div class="wrap">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="left">Blue Background</div>
        <div class="right">Red Background</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="left">Red Background</div>
        <div class="right">Blue Background</div>
    </div>
</div>


try to explain more what you are trying to acheive, and the issue you are facing.

I need first .column .left class in blue background and first .column .right class in red background. But second .column .left class in red background and second .column .right class in blue background.

After the edit in question and more context being provided, here is the updated code:
.wrap {display:flex;}
.column {display:flex;}

/* here is the code for the background updates*/
 .wrap {display:flex;}
.column {display:flex;flex-direction:row-reverse !important} 

.column:first-of-type .left{background-color:blue;}
.column:first-of-type .right{background-color:red;}

.column:last-of-type .left{background-color:red;}
.column:last-of-type .right{background-color:blue;}



  .wrap {display:flex;}
.column {display:flex;flex-direction:row-reverse !important} 

.column:first-of-type .left{background-color:blue;}
.column:first-of-type .right{background-color:red;}

.column:last-of-type .left{background-color:red;}
.column:last-of-type .right{background-color:blue;}
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="left">Blue Background</div>
        <div class="right">Red Background</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="left">Red Background</div>
        <div class="right">Blue Background</div>
    </div>
</div>



Update the flex-direction as per your required for the .column-first-of-type and .column-last-of-type

That was a mistake . I edited question. Please check my question again

I have updated the question based on the update!

Your answer is good. Please add .column {display:flex;flex-direction:row-reverse !important} effect also

You can play around with nth-child even/odd


.wrap {display:flex;}
.column {display:flex;flex-direction:row-reverse !important}
.wrap .column:nth-child(odd) div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.wrap .column:nth-child(odd) div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}

.wrap .column:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}

.wrap .column:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
}
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="left">Blue Background</div>
        <div class="right">Red Background</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="left">Red Background</div>
        <div class="right">Blue Background</div>
    </div>
</div>



